# C command line arguments, tokenizing

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, tokenize

am trying to write a function to parser command line arguments into a vector. The problem is i can't seem to eliminate the use of a global array of pointers as the vector.

The code is:

```
/** parse command line arguments into a global vector */
char vects[8][32] = {0};

int str_tokenizer(const char str[], char delim)
{
   extern char vects[8][32];
   int i,num_delim=0, num_vects;
   int str_len=strlen(str);

   for(i=0;i<str_len;i++)
   {
      if(str[i]==delim)
      num_delim++;
   }

   num_vects=num_delim+1;

   int x=0;
   vects[num_vects][32];
   for(i=0;i<num_vects;i++)
   {
      //printf("%i", i);
      int y=0;
      while(str[x]!=delim && str[x]!='\0')
      {
         //printf("%c", str[x]);
         vects[i][y++]=str[x++];
      }
      vects[i][y]='\0';
      x++;
   }
   return (num_vects);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why not use `getopt()` ? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-getopt.html

Comment: @jacekmigacz: Question is about C, not C++...

Comment: @brokenfoot `getopt` is for a very different task of interpreting option strings from an already-parsed array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing too much in one function. You should separate the tasks of parsing (just isolating the substrings of the original string, ie. discovering the starting and ending indices) on the one hand, and adding strings to a list on the other hand. To replace a 2D array, you can use a linked-list. But the parsing code should not have to worry about this, just scan for the next delimiter. Subtract the ending position from the starting position to get the length, and call an `append_string_to_list()` function, passing the full source string and the starting index and length.

By the way, you refer to this array

```
char vects[8][32] = {0};
```

as a "global array of pointers". It is not an array of pointers. It is an array of arrays of characters. To be sure, if you use a *slice* of the array, by not specifying the second index, then it will work *as if* it were a pointer -- and it will decay to a pointer in a function-call -- but a real array of pointers would look like this:

```
char *vects[8];
```